# Show/Hide Footer Groupfooter in Report View NOT Print Preview

Tags: vba, ms-access

Good Day Mates, I have experience in MS Access but am stumped, maybe because MS Access just doesn't cut the mustard.  In a nutshell, I am trying to build a Smart Report that does not need to be printed.  Based on buttons clicked on the report, the report in REPORT VIEW (notice NOT Print Preview mode) and I want to HIDE or SHOW the Groupfooter based on the button clicks.  Note: I am trying to avoid having numerous reports for each condition, just want a Smart Report to handle it.

Yes, Yes, Yes... I can make it work in PRINT PREVIEW using the Cancel command because the OnFormat event executes only in Print Preview mode.

```
Private Sub Groupfooter0_Format
   If <condition> then
      Cancel = True
   End if
```

The OnPaint Event will **NOT** allow visibility commands to be set and gives an Error to that point, and the Cancel doesn't work either.

```
If <condition> Then
    GroupFooter.Visible = True
Else
    GroupFooter.Visible = False
End If
```

Again, I am hoping someone has experience with successfully hiding and showing groupfooters in REPORT VIEW using the OnPaint event and NOT the OnFormat event, because as explained, the user will control the report via buttons.

Cheers,

Comment: Forms are intended for screen and reports for print. Making one serve for the other is bound to be frustrating. I don't think you will get what you want.

Comment: Yes and no... Making a form present data grouped and sub-grouped for displaying to management is just as troublesome.  Reports are excellent for this kind of presentation, I am just trying to extend functionality.  If you have code examples for a FORM to do what I need please send, it may work for what I need.   Keep in mind, the MS development made a decision to NOT allow visibility command to be addressed in Report View, not sure why, but C'est La Vie, looking for a work-around.

Comment: Why don't you prevent Print-View and allow only Print-Preview? No other options as Print-View is only one huge Page. Thats why formatting is missing.